# One background on grid divs and js scroll animation

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a HTML grid and 4 divs in. On one hand I want to apply a single background image on these one. On the other hand, I want to translate the divs on scroll.
It works but when I scroll, the background image is not extended anymore.

```html
<html>
  <body>
      <section id="home">
        <div id="bloc1" class="bloc"> </div>
        <div id="bloc2" class="bloc"> </div>
        <div id="bloc3" class="bloc"> </div>
        <div id="bloc4" class="bloc"> </div>
      </section>
  </body>
</html>
```

JS & CSS on JSFiddle : https://jsfiddle.net/SO3HSBF5/84wmv1cn/4/

Anyone can help me ?

Comment: What do you mean by ` It works but when I scroll, the background image is not extended anymore.`

Comment: @Awais look at the jsfiddle link

Comment: I have scened that, the background image is also moving with scroll as its attachment is fixed